# How should one handle locked rejected migrations?

Tags: discussion, flags, migration, locked-posts

Recently, I came across a question that was a poor migration from Programmers.SE - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638802/please-find-the-error it was a code dump and a really bad one that got closed quite promptly ("why isn't this code working").

Thats fine and good.  However, now there is a rather low quality blah question that is sitting in Stack Overflow (yea, I know... one of thousands).

This question is locked because of the migration process.  You can't vote on it. You can't comment on it. You can't edit it (if the OP had wanted to try to fix it up on SO so that it could be reopened some day).  You can't *delete* vote it.

So, what should be done with these questions?

To the best of my knowledge, the only thing that *can* be done is to flag them with a custom flag for a mod to come along and either unlock it or delete it... however, thats a chancy thing and these flags are occasionally declined ("declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it").

A query of [locked:yes is:question score:-100..0 closed:yes duplicate:no](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=locked%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+score%3A-100..0+closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano) finds a number of these questions that one can't do anything about and so they just sit there.  (not a perfect query - it finds merges that weren't closed as dups first also)

And before someone claims the roomba cleans them up - it doesn't.  The roomba won't touch locked questions.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192943/excel-macro-or-script-for-csv-search - there's one from over a year ago (just).

As described in [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year)

> **If the question is more than `30` days old, and ...**
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - **is not locked**
>
> **...or...**
>
> - it was closed and migrated to a different site
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.
>
> **If the question is more than `365` days old, and ...**
>
> - has a score of 0 *or* a score of 1 with a deleted owner
> - has no answers
> - **is not locked**
> - has a viewcount <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
> - has 1 or 0 comments
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.
>
> These checks are run every week across all sites.
>
> **If the question was closed more than `9` days ago, and ...**
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - **is not locked**
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past `9` days
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.

And no, that 30 day migration deletion is for things that were migrated *away*, not rejected migrations.

So, how should we handle these when we find them?  And are the mods all aware that if they aren't flagged, they're going to sit there exactly like it is ***forever***? No one, other than a mod, can fix them or delete them as they currently stand.

Sometimes these *do* [get cleaned up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726166/how-to-get-the-average-of-an-array) but that is likely more a meta-effect (different meta, not MSO) calling out specific posts publicly.

To that end, please consider the following posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638802/please-find-the-error
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192943/excel-macro-or-script-for-csv-search
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/25638802/
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/19013802/
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/18949243/
- [Caesar Cipher for CS50](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22007337/)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/17062085/
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/19987753/
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/22708923/

These posts are all locked (the only thing a meta effect can do is annoy the mods with flags - you can't vote on them), closed, migrations.  They will stay exactly like they are until a mod deletes them.

The question remains... should people who stumble across such questions flag them? or just let them sit there?

Comment: Sometimes such questions are used as "demonstration posts" so that they stay even with closure and downvotes. Posts can still be deleted by Community even after they are undeleted by a moderator.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Locked posts for history - those are well and good.  However, when another SE community makes the mistake of migrating a... well... crap question that gets closed in about 20 minutes - what is the value of keeping them around? Its also locked *because* of the migration (I know the reason its locked though I don't necessarily agree with it - its an automated thing) - so no one can fix it. Why should a +0/-6, no answer, question that was unfortunately migrated here rather than getting closed on its own site be preserved for all time?

Comment: @MichaelT - *"However, when another SE community makes the mistake of migrating a... well... crap question"* - I'm not sure I agree with this. I think the other site responsibility ends by routing a question to the correct site. Its not the other site's responsibility to rate a question for the new site or enforce policies on the the new site. I [personally] would not feel comfortable enforcing policies for Physics.SE or Math.SE or Server Fault. They have to police their own stuff.

Comment: @jww If the other site had a good idea that it would be closed for some reason (the "whats wrong with my code:" choice), it is not proper for the site to migrate it.  If it isn't going to be a good question on the target site, don't migrate it.  [Don't. Migrate. Crap.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/213963)  That aside, the questions are closed here. That isn't the issue I'm asking: Does SO want to keep that question locked, forever, in a state that it cannot be edited, deleted, or otherwise voted on except by special mod action?  Or should this be flagged to fix it?

Comment: @jww key question for you to consider... do you believe that any of these questions should remain on SO in their current state forever: [Please find the error!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25638802/), [Java tool for RE to DFA](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19013802/), [Learning R Programming Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18949243/), [Caesar Cipher Emergency](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22007337/), [Sophisticated UI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17062085/), [i need the first step to solve it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19987753/), [Rhino-Licensing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22708923/)

Comment: @jww Crap is crap.  It has to be a good question *first.*  **Then** it has to be on-topic on the target site.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that many of the original examples linked were removed in the many years that this question has been gathering dust. But I just *had* to fix that typo.

Speaking of editing, read the message put under rejected migrations:

> Votes, comments, and answers are locked due to the question being closed here, but it may be eligible for editing and reopening on the site where it originated.

It mocks me. The system knows I cannot edit it, yet the suggestion is there.

Here are the titles from the original list:

- Please find the error!
- Excel macro or script for CSV search?
- Please find the error!
- Java tool for RE to DFA
- Learning R Programming Question
- Caesar Cipher Emergency
- Sophisticated UI
- i need the first step to solve it
- Rhino-Licensing

All besides one (Caesar Cipher Emergency) are deleted, through what ever miracle. So I will provide an updated list:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748605/change-the-google-play-name-of-your-app?s=151|0.0000
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36847588/make-a-program-execute-only-from-verified-drive
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673270/i-am-not-able-to-understand-the-meaning-of-this-two-lines-of-code
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36345317/message-reading-prompt
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36290247/creating-a-function-to-clean-up-response-time-data-from-outliers-in-r
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120369/mongo-in-php-is-deprecated
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35605977/websphere-mq-with-c-sharp
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35282228/drum-sequencers-from-begginer-devs-standpoint
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898757/neat-python

---

[Here is a better search to find these creatures](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=locked%3Ayes+is%3Aquestion+score%3A-100..0+closed%3Ayes+duplicate%3Ano+migrated%3Ayes).

The system really needs to be fixed so that this doesn't happen. Most of these have already been deleted on the original site, and I have no clue why not here.