# This meta post is locked, but there is no message indicating that

Tags: support, specific-question, meta, migration, locked-posts

In the newest questions list, this showed up:

> -5 [i can not share long code stack overflow [on hold]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327851/1026459)

I was curious why it was still around, the snippet looked pretty bad, and so I navigated to use a delete vote on it.

This is what I found when I navigated there. There was no option to delete, and even the edit link was grayed out which was strange.

---

[image]

After inspecting it for a minute, I decided I would just downvote and move on, since that seemed to be the only option. At which point, the downvote failed with the message

[image]

And it became clear what was going on, but the reason I ask this question now is *how* did this happen? Is it because of the migration rejection paired with closure? Did a moderator lock it and the message was overwritten by the other two?

Why wasn't there an indication of being locked?

---

*edit* (placing this at the end because this happened after asking this question)

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/327851/timeline

animuson♦ has unlocked the post (thank you), but the main question about why there is no lock indication is still what is being asked here.

Comment: Yes, it is because of the rejected migration. It sucks that you then can't do anything anymore and it just sits there.

Comment: Yeah, I also wondered. But at least I can confirm, I met this behavior earlier on other migrated posts as well.

Comment: @Rizier123 - Hm, strange. Is the migration rejection done manually by a moderator, or is there some automatic metric involved?

Comment: @TravisJ It is because we closed it here it automatically rejected the migration.

Comment: We should have found a duplicate instead, they stay here

Comment: From Meta SE- [A question can also be rejected by the target community after it has already been migrated if it gets closed as a reason other than duplicate, or gets deleted (usually by the owner) on the target site.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: I see. So if a question is migrated here, and then closed here, it is determined to have been "migration rejected" which results in the lock. Okay, well at least that is part of the picture. But I suppose the main question still remains, **Why wasn't there an indication of being locked?** Is this a bug?

Comment: MSE related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130116/show-lock-banners-on-rejected-migrations/217065#217065  looks like status-bydesign

Comment: Related: [Are rejected migrations ever automatically deleted from the destination site; should they be?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243920/), [How should one handle locked rejected migrations?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270558)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We only display up to two post notices on any given post at a time so we don't flood the page with yellow boxes. The lock notice is super unimportant, especially when the migration rejected notice exists as that already implies it will be locked. So the lock notice gets hidden in favor of the other two notices.

The post has now been unlocked.

Comment: Can the word locked be bolded perhaps, so people like me who apparently struggle at reading don't miss that part :P

Comment: `<blink>locked</blink>` so tempting to write a userscript for that ...

Comment: Unfortunately, there's [a lot of them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=locked%3ayes%20migrated%3ayes) (only one result was a successful migration). The bitter irony is that the close votes indicating these questions are off-topic/unwelcome cause the questions to stick around well past the point where they would have been deleted.

Comment: The real question, of course, is why a Meta site can reject a migration. Meta is supposed to be a black hole, where nothing can be migrated out (at least, not by the community). Thus, it stands to reason that a migration to Meta should never be rejected. The question should just remain closed on Meta.

Comment: The lock is actually how a rejected migration is indicated. Migrated questions show as "migrated from"; migrated+locked questions show as "migration rejected from".